# How to avoid duplicate GET calls in Android with RXJava and Retrofit?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm using rxjava and retrofit 2 to handle my apps call requests. I did everything suggested on the internet, but still haven't found any better solution for my case. I have a widget in my Fragment, and when the user clicked the widget it will be opening new activity. This new activity calls `ActivityReward.java`.

When the `ActivityReward.java` is opened, it will make a call to the server to give data requested by the user. Here's a piece of code in my `RewardDataImplementation`:

```
@Override
public Observable<JsonObject> getRewardLists() {
    return myInterfaceApi
            .getRewardList()
            .compose(new RxSchedulerSwitcher<JsonObject>(ioScheduler, compScheduler));
}
```

Here's my Activity will call the API :

```
private void reqRewardList(MyConnector paymentConnector) {
        Map<Object, Object> requestParamMap = new HashMap<>();
        requestParamMap.put(
                MySyncronousRequestConstant.TYPE_KEY,
                SyncronousRequestConstant.GET_REWARD_LIST_REQUEST
        );
        MyConnector.postSyncronousRequest(requestParamMap);
    }
```

Here's my myInterfaceApi.java calls:

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@GET("/rewardList")
Observable<JsonObject> getRewardList();
```

Everything works fine whether the body is empty or filled, but I saw this on my log, the response becomes duplicates, like every time I opened the `ActivityReward.java`, the requests will call the server like twice, I don't want this to happen:

```
2021-06-30 15:54:41.083 31580-11282/com.example.myproject D/Retrofit: ---> HTTP GET https://localhost/rewardList
2021-06-30 15:54:41.083 31580-11282/com.example.myproject D/Retrofit: Accept: application/json
2021-06-30 15:54:41.083 31580-11282/com.example.myproject D/Retrofit: Content-Type: application/json
2021-06-30 15:54:41.083 31580-11282/com.example.myproject D/Retrofit: ---> END HTTP (no body)
2021-06-30 15:54:41.089 31580-11283/com.example.myproject D/Retrofit: ---> HTTP GET https://localhost/rewardList
2021-06-30 15:54:41.089 31580-11283/com.example.myproject D/Retrofit: Accept: application/json
2021-06-30 15:54:41.089 31580-11283/com.example.myproject D/Retrofit: Content-Type: application/json
2021-06-30 15:54:41.089 31580-11283/com.example.myproject D/Retrofit: ---> END HTTP (no body)
```

Is there any proper solution for my case? I want it when the user opens the `ActivityReward.java`, the API will only call the server once and **NOT** twice.

Comment: In what exactly place in `ActivityReward` you doing your network request?

Comment: Requesting for reward's lists @AlexanderSuvorov
It is basically will display a list of rewards

Comment: It is actually a long way, but I've edited my code above @AlexanderSuvorov

Comment: try to save the state of loading with a boolean like inProgress. whenever you call reqRewardList try to check whether it is true or not. if it is true it means it's in progress so don't call it again and return.

Comment: @XVallerie Key to understand the problem is to find the cause that makes your network request calls several times. 
The Information that you give is not enough to understand the problem because there is no any details of your app's business-logic or flow.
Try to debug your app to find the cause why this method runs two times. After find the problem you can answer your question here by yourself. It will be interesting to know what actually is going on there

Comment: @AlexanderSuvorov I've tried to debug and investigate the cause, and found it in here : 

`@Override
public Observable<JsonObject> getRewardLists() {
    return myInterfaceApi
            .getRewardList()
            .compose(new RxSchedulerSwitcher<JsonObject>(ioScheduler, compScheduler));
}`

when I put log.e here, it shows duplicate logs followed with the retrofit call

Comment: @behrad I didn't call it twice, it is automatically being called twice. I think there is a somewhat problematic in its RXStream or perhaps there is like stacked proccess